# Configure GCC target CPU

Tags: gcc, xilinx, neon

I have a Zynq 7000 target hardware. I consists of a dual core ARM Cortex A-9 with NEON and VFP co-processor. The co-processor must be enabled with an write access to the FPEXC register.

The [Enabling NEON and FPU for bare-metal](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472i/CJAHIEDH.html) shows corresponding code. The problem is that GCC (GNU assembler) doesn't accept the code. The error is:

> Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `msr fpexc,r0'

The complete minimal source code example is here:

```
  .text

  .global enableNeon
 enableNeon:
    mrc p15,0,r0,c1,c0,2    // Read CP Access register
    orr r0,#0x00f00000      // Enable full access to NEON/VFP (Coprocessors 10 and 11)
    mcr p15,0,r0,c1,c0,2    // Write CP Access register
    isb
    mov r0,#0x40000000      // Switch on the VFP and NEON hardware
    msr fpexc,r0            // Set EN bit in FPEXC
    bx lr

  .end
```

The GCC compiler of the Xilinx-SDK is started with these options:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -o "monitor.o" -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4  monitor.s
```

It looks like the GCC did not recognize that the CPU has the FPEXC register.
How can I configure the GCC to enable code generation for that CPU, coprocessor, and the special purpose register FPXEC?

Comment: You may need to build both `gcc` and `binutils` from their source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GNU assembler wants to see a VMSR instruction for this register:

```
 vmsr fpexc,r0            // Set EN bit in FPEXC
```